# Como obtener titulo desde table HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde tengo un evento al seleccionar un `td`.

Pero me gustaría obtener el titutlo `text` de ese `thead th`. Ejemplo la palabra `Titulo1` al seleccionar `00001`

```js
$('#main_table').on('click', 'span.show_detalle', function(e) {
    var cell = $(this).closest('td');
    var cellIndex = cell[0].cellIndex

    var texto = '';
    $('#main_table thead th').each(function(i, v) {
      if (cellIndex == i) {
        texto = $(v).text();
      }
    });

});
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Titulo1</th>
      <th>Titulo2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong><span class='show_detalle'>00001</span></strong></td>
      <td><strong><span class='show_detalle'>00002</span></strong></td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `$('#main_table thead th').each(function (i, v) {console.log($(v).text().trim())})` con este codigo puedes obtener los cabeceros de la tabla ya solo hazle los ajustes por index seleccionado para que te seleccione el th que necesites

Comment: @TheVicShow muchas gracias ahora como obtengo el `td:eq` que estoy seleccionando?
Tengo esto `$(this).closest('tr').find('td').index();`

Comment: Agregue ya la solucion en el codigo. Gracias @TheVicShow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como tienes el selector dentro de un `span` y este a su vez está dentro de un `strong` tienes que seleccionar el `td`, es por eso que le hago 2 `parentNode` al `this` para que obtenga el `td`, luego con el `cellIndex` obtienes el index que seleccionaste luego con la función que te pasé solo comparas el i con el `index` seleccionado y te muestra el titulo según el `td` que seleccionaste

```js
$('#main_table').on('click', 'span.show_detalle', function(e) {      
    let tdSelected = this.parentNode.parentNode.cellIndex;

    $('#main_table thead th').each(function (i, v) {
      if (i == tdSelected) {
        console.log("Header Selected", $(v).text());
      }
    })
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Titulo1</th>
      <th>Titulo2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong><span class='show_detalle'>00001</span></strong></td>
      <td><strong><span class='show_detalle'>00002</span></strong></td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
$('#main_table').on('click', 'span.show_detalle', function(e) {      

let index = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.cellIndex;

selected = $('#main_table thead th').eq(index).text();

console.log(selected);

  });
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js"></script>
<table id="main_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Titulo1</th>
      <th>Titulo2</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><strong><span class='show_detalle'>00001</span></strong></td>
      <td><strong><span class='show_detalle'>00002</span></strong></td>
      <td>

      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```